# Display part of JLabel in bold

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

People have asked similar questions to this but I don't think they quite help with my question.

I've got a GUI with a JLabel that displays the current value of a String. I would like to put part of a string in bold. The string itself can vary, so I'm not sure HTML will be of help?

```
String myStr1 = "abc";
String myStr2 = "this bit in bold";
String myStr3 = "now back to normal";
myLabel.setText(myStr1 + [BOLD] myStr2 + myStr3);
```

It seems like this should be simple, I assumed there'd be an escape character or something, but I can't find an easy way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use HTML tags

```
myLabel.setText("<html>" + str1 + "<B>" + str2 + "</B>" + str3 + "</html>")
```

See: [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Comment: <html> tag required to the start of the given string.

Comment: sorry, ignore my last comment, I forgot a +

Comment: Thanks for the help but strangely it doesn't seem to work. I wonder if all the text is already bold in a JLabel?

Comment: yes, I think it's something to do with that because if I use the html for underline that works. To be honest, that will do, though ideally I'd prefer to use bold. Thanks again for the help, really quick and spot on.

Comment: There is a bold JLabel component in the example linked above.  See the main of the source code of that example for a possible workaround to your "bold tag doesn't make bold text" issue.(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/HtmlDemoProject/src/components/HtmlDemo.java)